# Java: Get file path name as Internal storage instead of storage/emulated/0

Tags: java, android, file

Is there a way to get the file path of any directory as their common name? (Like, if I save the file to /storage/emulated/0/Documents I should get the path as Internal Storage/Documents. Is there any function like file.getSimplePath() or something?

Comment: What’s the problem with storage/emulated/0/Documents? & storage/emulated/0/ is the usable internal storage.

Comment: @DarShan But i created a toast: `Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

It toasts that it saved to /storage/emulated/0.
I want it to toast that it saved to Internal Storage. is there any function to get the file name as that (like `file.getCommonName()`) or something?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0` is external storage to begin with. But of course you can toast what you want. A textual replace would do.

Comment: You could simply `substring` the path after the last `/` & show that in the Toast, or just show `Saved Successfully` in your Toast.

Comment: @blackapps how do I replace the text?

Comment: String.replace(); File.getName();.